# in Spark Scala, how to pass date parameters to explode specific date range?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parameter-passing

Let us say I have a data frame with 2 columns "id": String and "ds": String in the form of yyyy-mm-dd.

What I am trying to do is: given specified start_date and end_date, generate all the possible combinations of id and date combinations that have dates between these two dates, later I will fill in those gap dates

Right now my code is like this

```
var tempDf = df.selectExpr("id").distinct().selectExpr("id","explode(sequence(date('2022-04-01'),date('2022-08-01'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as ds1")
```

My questions is how to make the start_date and end_date dynamic?

I tried to set start_date and end_date first and then passing like this, it did not work. The complier did not complain and it ran, but it returned nothing.  Thanks for help

```
var tempDf = df.selectExpr("id").distinct().selectExpr("id","explode(sequence(date('{start_date}'),date('{end_date}'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as ds1")
```

@soulmachine's answer is incorrect

something like below will work, the reason is that string substitution happens at compile time, to make it work at run time, manually replace the variable.

```
val query = s"explode(sequence(date('${start_date}'),date('${end_date}'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as ds1".replace("${start_date}", start_date).replace("${end_date}", end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about composing the query string first, and then pass it to `selectExpr()`?

```scala
val start_date = "2022-04-01"
val end_date = "2022-08-01"
val query = s"explode(sequence(date('$start_date'),date('$end_date'),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as ds1"
var tempDf = df.selectExpr("id").distinct().selectExpr("id", query)
```

Comment: this does not work, as the val query is now an literal string and does not substitute the start_date and end_date

Comment: I updated the code, it should work now